# How can I get the variable of build configuration of multi-config generator in CMake?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

I want to check the current build configuration when I use cmake and VS2019. I know CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE won't work in multi-configuration generator, so how can I know the build type?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
  if(USE_VCPKG)
    if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    #if($<CONFIG:Debug>)
        find_program(TOOL_WINDEPLOYQT NAMES windeployqt.debug.bat )
    else()
        find_program(TOOL_WINDEPLOYQT NAMES windeployqt)
  endif()
```

command:

```
cmake --build ./build --config Debug
```

---

According to @starball 's answer, I look into document of generator expression.

> Generator expressions are allowed in the context of many target
> properties, such as LINK_LIBRARIES, INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES,
> COMPILE_DEFINITIONS and others. They may also be used when using
> commands to populate those properties, such as
> target_link_libraries(), target_include_directories(),
> target_compile_definitions() and others.

then the right expression should be:

```
  if(USE_VCPKG)
       set(TOOL_WINDEPLOYQT "windeployqt")

       add_custom_command(TARGET Demo POST_BUILD
       COMMAND ${TOOL_WINDEPLOYQT}$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:.debug.bat>
               $<TARGET_FILE:Demo>
       COMMENT "Running windeployqt... "
  )
  endif()
```

Answer (score 1):

CMake variables are a configure-time thing. What you're looking for is something to tell you what configuration is being generated, which is a generation-time thing. You want generator expressions.

You can use [the `$<CONFIG>` generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:CONFIG). Only certain contexts support generator expressions. You'll nee to consult the documentation to see if the context where you want to use a generator expression supports that type of generator expression. There's a shorthand generator expression to expand a value conditionally based on what the configuration / build-type being generated is: the `$<CONFIG:cfgs>` generator expression.

For example, `find_program` is not documented to support generator expressions, which makes sense, since it's a configuration-time mechanism- not a generation-time mechanism. Assuming the place where you want to use `windeployqt` is in a context that supports generator expressions, such as [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html), and if `windeployqt.debug.bat` is in the same directory as `windeployqt`, then what you could do is continue finding `windeployqt` at configuration time, and then in your custom target or whatever needs to know the location of `windeployqt`, use something along the lines of `"${TOOL_WINDEPLOYQT}$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:.debug.bat>"`. At configuration time, CMake will evaluate a command argument of `"${TOOL_WINDEPLOYQT}$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:.debug.bat>"` to `"/whatever/path/to/windployqt/was/found$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:.debug.bat>"`, and then at generation time, the `$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>` part will be expanded to `1` if the configuration being generated is `Debug` or `RelWithDebInfo`, or `0` otherwise, and then `$<0:.debug.bat>` would be expanded to an empty string, and `$<1:.debug.bat>` would be expanded to `.debug.bat`.